# Devise reset password notification via SMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, backend

I'm currently stuck figuring out how to send the reset password notification via sms instead of email to a phone number.

We have allowed email to be null, as users may sign up with out an email but phone number is compulsory.

Would really appreciate some advice on this.

Comment: You can override devise passwords controller #create method to send notification via sms.

Comment: Could you show me an example of it? I believe that we need to override the recoverable module :-

        def send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
          recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
          recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions if recoverable.persisted?
          recoverable
        end